# "She became involved with a married man [who is] many years her senior." - Is "who is" required for correct grammar?

Tags: clauses

> She became involved with a married man many years her senior.

Is it correct in grammar?

I suppose it should be

> She became involved with a married man who is many years her senior.

Is my opinion correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

She became involved with a married man who is many years her senior.

"Who is many years her senior" is a relative clause. I think You can reduce a relative clause  if the relative pronoun that, which, or who is the subject of the clause and there is a linking verb "be".  In such a case, you can omit the relative pronoun and the verb form be (is, are, was, were, etc.).

So the sentence without "who is" is also correct grammatically.

Comment: "who is many years her senior" should be " who was many years her senior" to match the tense of became.

Comment: Karen, I think you can use who is/was in the sentence if you think the statement is still true or up-to-date.